# WebApi Restful route with filter

Tags: rest, routes, asp.net-web-api

I want to provide a GetAll api with a filter parameter like so:

```
/api/v1/location/amsterdam/order/?filter=x
```

but with this route:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/v1/location/{location}/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional}
);
```

and this url:

```
/api/v1/location/amsterdam/order/?filter=x
```

I get an exception:

> "No action was found on the controller 'Order' that matches the request."

The 'order' controller has the following methods:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
public IQueryable<OrderDTO> Get(string filter)
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
```

When I remove the `{location}` segment from the route and the url (`/api/v1/location/order/?filter=x`), the request **is** matched by the `Get(string filter)` method.

What am I doing wrong? What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
/api/v1/location/amsterdam/order?filter=x
```

The `/` before `?` is not useful.